# How to upgrade SQLite database in Assets folder in

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an Android app in which I have created an SQLite database in the Assets folder. Now I want to upgrade this database in Assets folder, But it allows only to upgrade the local internal storage database not the one in the Assets folder.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        switch (oldVersion) {
            case 1:
                executeSQLScript(database, "update_v2.sql");
            case 2:
                executeSQLScript(database, "update_v3.sql");
        }
    }
}
```

So only way I think to upgrade the Assets folder database is to change the database file manually and update the apk. But I want this to be done programmatically and that too without changing the apk. e.g. get the latest DB changes from some server and update the assets folder database.

I have gone through many articles on the internet and its mentioned there that Assets will ReadOnly. You can not write. but this is a very basic requirement. I think there has to be some workaround for this kind of requirement.

So, in short, my question is that is this possible to upgrade the database without changing the code (upgrading the apk)?

**Update:**

The main problem is that I have WebView in the app. HTML and js files are inside the Assets folder. I can upgrade the local internal storage database. but If I upgrade the database I need to send this data to the javascript files inside the assets folder. The Main problem is that this data is very large approximately 40 MB. There is no internet connectivity also, so you can not send data through the network also. So when I try to send this data from the native code to JavaScript code, the application crashes every time. So I thought to have the DB in Assets folder, keep a copy in the native app. If there is DB upgrade then upgrade the Assets folder DB instead of sending this large data from native code to JS code. I have not found any proper solution for this until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are read-only at runtime. You cannot modify the assets in an Android app from within the Android app. The only way to update assets is to ship a new version of the APK with the new assets.

Comment: @viveknuna "I think there has to be some workaround for this kind of requirement" -- sure. Don't use assets the way that you are. For example, you could download your SQL script to a file. Then, when you want to reset the database (or whatever you're trying to do here), look for the file and use it, falling back to assets if there is no file. IOW, come up with a more flexible system for determining the source of your SQL.

Comment: Please check the Update section in question

Comment: @viveknuna: I do not understand your scenario. Regardless, modifying assets is simply not an option. APKs are digitally signed and cannot be modified at runtime without invalidating the digital signature. Assets, like most resources, remain in the APK and are read from the APK as needed.

Comment: So how to send large data from native java code to JS and that too without internet connection?

Comment: @viveknuna: I do not know much about the data (other than its size), how you are using it, or where it comes from. You might want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] explaining where the data is coming from and how you are using it. There, you can ask for help in identifying ways to update that data that does not involve replacing an asset.